# Resuming posting a question resumes the wrong one

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

I wrote a nice bug report about an error I got after posting a question, but was told that I could only post 1 question every 900 seconds.

So I waited until now and then chose to resume my post. But it resumed the question I successfully posted *before* the failed one. :-(

So now I'm reporting *that* instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry about that! Fixed in version 0.1.62 coming out later tonight.